# Angular-cliで作ったWebページを公開する方法

Tags: angular2

フレームワーク初心者です。
初めて`Angular-cli`を使って、Webページを簡単に作ってみたのですが
実際の`index.html`には対してコードが書いてなく、コンポーネントで色々分けて作りました。
その`Angular2`で作ったものはどうやってサーバーにあげる感じなのかわからないです。
`node_modules`や`dist`など色々ファイルがありますが、これを全部含めてあげたらよろしいのでしょうか？
わかる方がいらしたら教えて頂きたいです。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 無事解決されたようですが、このままだと質問が解決していないように見えてしまうので、結論をご自身で回答として投稿していただけませんか？加えて、回答左のチェックマークをクリックしていただくと解決済みという目印になります（ただしこの操作は質問から48時間以上経たないといけないので、もし覚えていたらで…）

Comment: わかりました。アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4):

**自己解決**
色々調べてみた結果、Web上にあげるファイルは
ターミナルで`ng serve`したディレクトリ（`ng serve`してない状態）で`ng build`というコマンドを実行したら、`dist`というファイル中にweb用のファイルが追加されます。
その`dist`ファイルをそのまま上げたらおっけーという感じだと思います。
おさがわせしました。